# erstellen und herstellen

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Sind erstellen und herstellen grundsätzlich unterschiedlich, oder können meistens austauschbar verwendet werden ?

Zum Beispiel, eine Liste erstellen, ein Ranking erstellen, eine Beziehung herstellen, ein Haus erstellen : es geht immer um den Bau, die Fabrikation von etwas.

Mein Wörterbuch gibt gewisse Verbindungen :

- erstellen mit Haus, Liste, Verzeichnis, Rangliste etc.
- herstellen mit Beziehung, Kontakt, industriel etc.

Die Wörter liegen aber sehr nah, und mir scheint, dass ich sie zu oft verwechsele.

Comment: Weitere "Paare": (h)erbitten, (h)erfinden, (h)ereilen, (h)ergeben, (h)errichten...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Erstellen" kann man nur Abstrakta, vor allem Dokumente, z.B. Tabellen, Listen, auch Listen von Häusern, aber definitiv *nicht* Häuser. (Häuser werden auch nicht "hergestellt", außer man redet sehr allgemein über die gesamte Produktionswirtschaft, sondern *gebaut*.)

"Herstellen" kann man diverse Produkte aller Art, also sowohl Schuhe als auch Erdbeereis (im übertragenen Sinne z.B. auch einen Kontakt, Konsens etc.). Der Fokus liegt dabei neben dem konkreten Arbeiten mit physischem Material auch auf der *massenhaften* Produktion. "Dokumente produzieren" würde nahelegen, dass die Dokumente massenhaft mit geringen Unterschieden und mutmaßlich geringem Wert entstehen.

Answer (score 3):

[DWDS:erstellen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/erstellen) und [DWDS: herstellen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/herstellen) zeigen unter dem Abschnitt *Typische Verbindungen* praktisch keine Überlappung. Das deckt sich mit meiner Einschätzung, dass die Wörter praktisch nie austauschbar sind, obwohl sie eine ähnliche Bedeutung haben.

Die einzige Eselsbrücke ist, dass nach *wieder* eher *herstellt* folgt, was dem englischen *reestablish* entspricht.

> ... der Kontakt zur Raumsonde wurde wieder hergestellt
> ... wurde die öffentliche Ordnung durch Einsatz des Militärs wieder hergestellt.

Comment: "wiederherstellen" im Sinne von "wieder instand setzen" schreibt man aber zusammen: [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wiederherstellen)